# How do I customize the pagination items in this Laravel 8 application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)** in Laravel 8.

The **ArticlesController** controller I have this method to display the *paginated* articles:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Article;
use App\Models\Comment;

class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

    // Articles per page
    protected $per_page = 12;

    public function index(Request $request) {

        // Search query
        $qry = $request->input('search');

        $articlesQuery = Article::where('title', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%')
                                            ->orWhere('short_description', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%')
                                            ->orWhere('content', 'like', '%' . $qry . '%');

        // Search results count
        if ($qry) {
            $article_count = $articlesQuery->count();
        }   

        $articles = $articlesQuery->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($this->per_page);   
        $featured_articles = Article::where('featured', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/index', 
            array_merge($this->data, [
                'search_query' => $qry,
                'articles' => $articles,
                'featured_articles' => $featured_articles,
                'article_count' => $article_count ?? null
            ])
        );
    }
    
}
```

The pagination, in the *plain HTML* template, looks like this:

```
<nav class="pgn">
  <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="pgn__prev" href="#0">Prev</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">1</a></li>
      <li><span class="pgn__num current">2</span></li>
      <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">3</a></li>
      <li><span class="pgn__num dots">…</span></li>
      <li><a class="pgn__num" href="#0">4</a></li>
      <li>
         <a class="pgn__next" href="#0">Next</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

#### The goal

The goal is to keep the pagination structure above, in Laravel's Blade.

#### The problem

The code below works for the "Next" and "Prev" buttons, but not the links in between.

```
<nav class="pgn">
  <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="pgn__prev" href="{{ $articles->withQueryString()->previousPageUrl() }}">Prev</a>
      </li>

        {!! $articles->withQueryString()->links() !!}

      <li>
         <a class="pgn__next" href="{{ $articles->withQueryString()->nextPageUrl() }}">Next</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

#### Questions

1. What causes this bug?
2. What is the easiest fix?

Comment: `links()` should return HTML, so you should wrap it with `{!! !!}`. Did you try this before?

Comment: @Daniel That does not work as expected either. It does not "wrap around" the existing HTML structure.

Comment: you don't need to use unescaped echos, the `render` method which `links` calls returns an `Htmlable` object which bypasses escaping as it is prerendered HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom pagination, I'd recommend to make use of a custom "view".

Basically, what would you have to do (which you have already done), is define a limit, and then basically do the following:

you create your view file (which will be the custom paginator) - name it however you want to name it. I'll name it `custom.blade.php`

This view has to be created after running the command: `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

here you can find a bit more in the documentation about it: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

```
@if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
    <li class="disabled"><span>← Previous</span></li>
        @else
            <li>
                <a class="pgn__prev" href="{{ $articles->withQueryString()->previousPageUrl() }}">Prev</a>
            </li>
        @endif


      
        @foreach ($elements as $element)
           
            @if (is_string($element))
                <li class="disabled"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
            @endif


           
            @if (is_array($element))
                @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                    @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                        <li class="active my-active"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                    @else
                        <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach


        
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
            <li>
                <a class="pgn__next" href="{{ $articles->withQueryString()->nextPageUrl() }}">Next</a>
            </li>
        @else
    <li class="disabled"><span>Next</span></li>
@endif
```

And finally, on the view where you want to make use of the custom pagination:

```
{{ $articles->links(‘path.pagination.custom') }}
```

(just make sure to have the correct path)

edit: It's a bit hard for me to give a definitive answer without looking at the project itself, but I hope this at least helps somehow.

Comment: Where does `$elements as $element` come from?

Comment: I think it's detected automatically. Let me edit the answer, I forgot something important.

Comment: The project is **[HERE](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)** and at the top of the post. I get an `Undefined variable: elements` error.